# Django form widget value

Tags: django

I'm setting a widget on Django as a text field instead of an integerfield like it is on the database, because it is a pin field, and we want it to be able to start with 0s, I have been able to handle adding 0s in python thanks to zfill, so now I was wondering if it was possible to change the value of a widget, so I can add say value=pin.zfill(4), and pass it directly on the form.

Comment: I would make the argument that a PIN is not really a number, and store it in the database as a CharField with some (preferably database level) validation to make sure it only contains 0-9 at a specific length. It would probably make things much simpler.

Comment: @Knyght I agree 100% with you, but where I work if we want to change a field on the database it has to go through a gigantic process and might take weeks to get it done, the joys, so this workaround while not the best is however our best option

Comment: In that case, if I understand your use case correctly, you can make your own widget class to render the form html however you like (with your extra 0s)

Comment: Yes I tried that, it shows as a textfield but I can't assign a value to it, if I use the name of the property I created in the model it gives me an error (the way the form was created is kinda weird I inherited the code), so was just mostly wondering if there was a way to just set value=something if not then I will use Javascript